# @Where annotation cannot be resolved

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have an old `Spring-MVC` project, developed in: `Hibernate 4.3.8.Final`, `JPA version 1.7.2` and `Java 7`, for problem with old JS component I need to recreate this project in a `Spring-Boot` project (using `Spring5`, `Java8`, `Thymeleaf` and `Bootstrap`) .

I can't lost the old DB, I can not lose or change the structure of the DB, so I'm rewriting the classes of the Domain but I have an error with an annotation.

This is the code of Domain Class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="order", cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
@JsonBackReference("job-order")
@Where(clause="year = '0'")
private List<Job> jobYearI = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy="order", cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
@JsonBackReference("job-order")
@Where(clause="year = '1'")
private List<Job> jobYearII = new ArrayList<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy="order", cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
@JsonBackReference("job-order")
@Where(clause="year = '2'")
private List<Job> jobYearIII = new ArrayList<>();
```

I need to populate the jobYearX based on the year value, but in the new project I have this error:

> The import org.hibernate.annotations.Where cannot be resolved

There is a way to resolve it?
Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

My Job Class

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"order_certification", "year"}))
public class Job extends AbstractDomain {


    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(nullable=false, updatable=false)
    @JsonManagedReference("job-orderCertification")
    private OrderCertification orderCertification;


    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    @Column(nullable=false, name="year", updatable=false)
    private Year year;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, its seems to me that your new application doesn't have a hibernate-core dependency at runtime. Where and Filter annotations are hibernate-specific and still not deprecated.